# Power BI: Add a chart from a streaming dataset to Power BI desktop report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, data-stream

I have created a Power BI reporting file (.pbix) with some pages and charts. One of the page has a few charts that show LIVE data, but the charts are from regular SQL Server VIEW datasets.

I created a Push Streaming Dataset, and while I can create a visual from it in a new Power BI desktop file, I am unable to do so in my current file.

If I try to add a Power BI dataset from the 'Get Data' menu, it throws an error saying:

> The Connect live option for this file is disabled because it already
>   contains data from another data source. You cannot explore live data
>   and connect to another type of data source in the same file. Create a
>   new file to explore live data.

My data is in an on-premise SQL Server and I am unable to add my datasets to the Power BI Service Web App. How can I merge my visual that uses the Push Data Streaming, along with my other existing visuals.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in my project. What we did is, we used a dashboard in Power BI service to visualize tile from separate reports. That might not be your case but it is one consideration.